# Drag from cdkDropList and drop as a card in a canvas

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I'm taking the liberty of posting because I haven't found any answer to my problem :(

I'm working with Angular 8 and I need to have a list of items that can be dragged from this list and dropped into a canvas where it could stagnate at the drop location.

The only thing I was able to do was to have a list of draggable items and when I drag one, watch if the cursor is in the canvas using event and then if there is a drop while the cursor is in the canvas:

1 - Delete the element from the list

2 - Make an element appear in the canvas at the last known position of the cursor

By doing this, it does the job, but I feel like I'm not doing it right.

Do you have any suggestions? Seeing a component of a library doing this natively? 
Many thanks for yours answers :)

Comment: If you post a stackblitz I'd be glad to chime in. I have something similar that i'm also tweaking.